# mypy complains Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[str]", expected "str") when a function can only return str

Tags: python, mypy

```
import os
from typing import Optional

_DEFAULT = 'abc'

def _get_value(param: Optional[str]) -> str:
    return param or os.getenv("PARAM", _DEFAULT)
```

For this function, mypy would complain

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[str]", expected "str")
```

but I thought this function will never return `None`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mypy` type checker doesn't seem to be able to parse `or` conditions. You have to explicitly check for `None` values:

```
if param:
    return param
else:
    return os.getenv("PARAM", _DEFAULT)
```

Edit: The above code technically checks for *falsy* values instead of `None` but it is functionally equivalent to your example.

Answer (score 1):

mypy seems to be missing some inference of "old style ternary" functions -- those of the form `A or B` or `A and B or C`

looking at `reveal_type` for the three expressions

```
# reveal_type(param)
t.py:9: note: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.str, None]'
# reveal_type(os.getenv("PARAM", _DEFAULT)
t.py:10: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
# param or reveal_type(os.getenv("PARAM", _DEFAULT)
t.py:11: note: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.str, None]'
```

you can get around this by using a true ternary:

```py
def _get_value(param: Optional[str]) -> str:
    return param if param is not None else os.getenv("PARAM", _DEFAULT)
```